# Email to automatically add calendar reminder to their calendars

Tags: calendar, html-email

Is there a way to send mass email and automatically add a calendar reminder the users' calendars? I've found you can export an .ics file and link to that where users can import into their program of choice,  but what about something that will do it automatically to any calendar? I've used this article to follow, but nothing for automatically adding to the user's calendar nor do we use that email service.

http://www.whatcounts.com/2013/07/feature-friday-add-calendar-events-in-publicaster-edition/

Answer (score 0):

You can not force someone to automatically download the .ics, as you can imagine, auto downloading anything in email would pose a security risk to the reader.

All you can do is host the .ics (or any file really) on the web and hyperlink to it with a 'Save to Calendar' type linkin your email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to do this *automatically*. One of the important reason is JavaScript is not allowed by most of the email client.

I think the best way to show user a event and make it easy to add to their calendar is generate a .ics file and attach to the email as an attachment. Many email client, like Gmail, will find it and display it as a part of the email.

Here is a reference of .ics file format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar