# Event details from email to auto populate on calendar

Tags: email, html-email

Does anyone know how to add event details from an email to a calendar automatically? The best example I have seen on this is when making a flight confirmation, the event will show in the calendar. Any tips, insights greatly appreciated

I have added the event date and time to the pre-header text and body copy, but calendar does not receive the information

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154275/email-to-automatically-add-calendar-reminder-to-their-calendars

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831877/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-add-an-entry-to-a-calendar